# How to display an array item in dancer?

Tags: perl, dancer

I try to display an array item in dancer, here is the code:

```
get '/' => sub {
  my @rows = ('aaa','bbb','ccc');
  template 'crud.tt', {'rows' => \@rows};
};
```

and the template is:

```
  <h2><% $rows[1] %></h2>
  <h2><% rows[1] %></h2>
  <% FOREACH r IN rows %>
    <p><% r %></p>
  <% END %>
```

In the h2 element show nothing, what is the right way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't pass anything but a simple scalar value if you are using the default `Dancer` template engine. But if you enable `Template::Toolkit` as the engine then all kinds of things are possible.

You can do this globally by setting `template: template_toolkit` in the YAML config file, or you can set it just for this route by writing

```
get '/' => sub {
  my @rows = ('aaa','bbb','ccc');
  set template => 'template_toolkit';
  template 'crud.tt', { rows => \@rows };
};
```

Your template will look like

```
<h2><% rows.1 %></h2>
<% FOREACH r IN rows %>
<p><% r %></p>
<% END %>
```

and you will need

```
use Template;
```

to load the `Template::Toolkit` module before you use either method